# How can I start playing d&d 5e as a beginner?

Tags: dnd-5e

I am completely new to role-playing games, yet have an experience with board games. How should I start d&d without it overwhelming me?

Comment: Welcome to our stack! A duplicate question is A-okay here, but please let us know if that doesn't answer it and why. Also, feel free to take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more info. Happy Gaming!

Comment: Quirk of the stack, but duplicates are a good thing here, as they help others (who use the same search terms as you) find the other question. So we've undeleted this to keep it as a pointer. (No, we don't know why the site prompts deletion either, but we can't change that unfortunately.)